# EF Core not tracking the correct property in a unit of work scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This question is an abstract of the problem that I am facing: consider the below,

I have entities with the following properties

```cs
public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Status can be 0 (New) or 1 (Deleted).

I have a service call which alters the entity from 0 -> 1 which is called through the service. The repository involved **does not call context.SaveChanges()**, instead this is handled farther up the chain in middleware.

This looks like:

```cs
var entity = await Context.Entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

entity.SetDeleted();
```

Where the `SetDeleted` method changes the property from 0 to 1.

Then, in another service method (in the same unit of work) this is read to check if there is an entity which isn't deleted. This is where the problem occurs.

The code looks like:

```cs
var entities = context.Entities.Any(x => x.Status != 1);
```

Usually you would expect the graph to not be returned, but unfortunately it is. Strangely enough when you execute the `ToList()` function and then run the same operation it doesn't include the graph. This means that if you have the below:

```cs
var entities = await Context.Entities.Where(x => x.Status!= 1).ToListAsync();
var secondFilter = entities.Where(x => x.Status != 1).ToList();
```

The `entities` **will contain the entity**, the `secondFilter` **will not** contain the entity despite it being subject to the same rules.

Has anyone had this problem, does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You never persist any changes, so why do you expect anything to be deleted? The Unit-of-Work is the DbContext. Nothing is persisted until you call `SaveChanges`. That's when the UoW commits. What you posted never persists anything

Comment: `Usually you would expect the graph to not be returned,` no, I would expect the same objects to be loaded, because nothing was deleted yet. Calling `Enumerable.ToList()` on a `List<> doesn't anything, much less the database. It doesn't even query the database, it queries the already loaded objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by-design behavior of EF.

When you have a tracked entity, and query the same entity from the database, the tracked entity is never overwritten.

After

```
var entity = await Context.Entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

entity.SetDeleted();
```

You have one tracked entity, with a modified `Status`.

This

```
var entities = await Context.Entities.Where(x => x.Status!= 1).ToListAsync();
```

Runs a SQL query and finds the *same* entity as its Status=0 in the database.  But when when EF tries to add the entity to the change tracker it discovers that there's a modified version already there, and so it discards the data read from the database and adds the existing modified entity to the `entities` collection.  Then this

```
var secondFilter = entities.Where(x => x.Status != 1).ToList();
```

returns nothing because `entity` has Status=1.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand thanks; what would be the workaround for this? As I'm using a UoW solution I don't particularily want to call context.SaveChanges()

Perhaps some kind of outer transaction?

Comment: You could look in the `Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity>` or `Context.Entities.Local` instead of looking in the database.